# Recursion in XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to add a attribute type="bottom line" to the row whose following sibling has entry with table notes,I did it..But the question is that if there is merged columns I have to add type="bottom line" to that entries also, and this adding should stop when entry count are equal.

Input XML

```
<table>
    <row>
        <entry id="1"></entry>
        <entry id="2"></entry>
        <entry id="3" merged="1"></entry>
        <entry id="4"></entry>
        <entry id="5"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="1"></entry>
        <entry id="2"></entry>
        <entry id="3" merged="1"></entry>
        <entry id="4"></entry>
        <entry id="5"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="6" merged="1"></entry>
        <entry id="7"></entry>
        <entry id="8"></entry>
        <entry id="9"></entry>
    </row>

    <row>
        <entry id="10"></entry>
        <entry id="11"></entry>
        <entry id="12"></entry>
        <entry id="13"></entry>

        <entry id=“14"></entry>

    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="15"></entry>
        <entry id="16"></entry>
        <entry id="17"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
    </row>
</table>
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
<table>
    <row>
        <entry id="1"></entry>
        <entry id="2"></entry>
        <entry id="3" merged="1"></entry>
        <entry id="4"></entry>
        <entry id="5"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="1"></entry>
        <entry id="2"></entry>
        <entry id="3" merged="1" type="bottom line"></entry>
        <entry id="4"></entry>
        <entry id="5"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="6" merged="1" type="bottom line"></entry>
        <entry id="7"></entry>
        <entry id="8"></entry>
        <entry id="9"></entry>
    </row>

    <row>
        <entry id="10"></entry>
        <entry id="11"></entry>
        <entry id="12"></entry>
        <entry id="13"></entry>

        <entry id="14"></entry>

    </row>
    <row>
        <entry id="15" type="bottom line"></entry>
        <entry id="16" type="bottom line"></entry>
        <entry id="17" type="bottom line"></entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
        <entry type="table notes">test</entry>
    </row>
</table>
```

The XSLT I wrote so far:

- for add bottom line to table notes

  bottom line

for merged entries

```
<xsl:template match="row/entry[@merged]" mode="merged">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">bottom line</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row[last()-1]">
    <xsl:if test="count(./entry) &gt; count(./preceding-sibling::row/entry)">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="merged"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
thanks..

Answer (score 1):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- change the desired elements -->
    <xsl:template match="row[following-sibling::*[1]/entry/@type = 'table notes']/entry | entry[@merged]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">bottom line</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template is the identity transform template to copy all the attributes and nodes.
The second template adds the `@type` to the desired elements.

Comment: Here,type bottom line added to all entry[@merged] ,but I want to restrict this .When current row entries count equal to preceding row entries count this attribute should not be added.Is there any idea on that @Lingamurthy.

Comment: @user2490093 I didn't understand that. Can you please explain more. Does your expected output have that you commented?